# How to do custom repository using TypeORM (MongoDB) in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I have a question. With `@EntityRepository` decorator being marked as deprecated in `typeorm@^0.3.6`, what is now the recommended or TypeScript-friendly way to create a custom repository for an entity in NestJS? A custom repository before would look like this:

```
// users.repository.ts
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UsersRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async createUser(firstName: string, lastName: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = this.create({
      firstName,
      lastName,
    });

    await this.save(user);

    return user;
  }
}
```

And since NestJS is by default configured with TypeScript support, I will be able to call `usersRepository.createUser()` without an issue in a service like this:

```
// users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UsersRepository)
    private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
  ) {}

  async createUser(firstName: string, lastName: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.createUser(firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```

This is how the modules would import the custom repository:

```
// users.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Also the reason why I mentioned MongoDB here is because I tried using `typeorm@0.2` where `@EntityRepository` is still supported but I receive an error when I tried to import it in the module stating `Repository not found` or something. Do note, if I chose `postgresql` as my database in TypeORM with the same changes above, I don't have this issue. Hence I went to check the latest only to find out it is already deprecated, I also didn't find any example in NestJS documentation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this which allows to call custom methods but also inherited ones. It seems that this "issue" is not too popular yet but there is definitely some chatter about it within the typeorm GitHub threads: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9013

The following solution uses MySQL as underlying database driver but I assume it will work for MongoDB as well.

**team.repository.ts**

```
import {DataSource, Repository} from 'typeorm';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Team} from '@Domain/Team/Models/team.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TeamRepository extends Repository<Team>
{
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource)
    {
        super(Team, dataSource.createEntityManager());
    }

    /**
     * Add a basic where clause to the query and return the first result.
     */
    async firstWhere(column: string, value: string | number, operator = '='): Promise<Team | undefined>
    {
        return await this.createQueryBuilder()
                         .where(`Team.${column} ${operator} :value`, {value: value})
                         .getOne();
    }
}
```

**team.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Team} from '@Domain/Team/Models/team.entity';
import {TeamRepository} from '@Domain/Team/Repositories/team.repository';

@Injectable()
export class TeamService
{
    constructor(
        private teamRepository: TeamRepository,
    )
    {
    }

    async create(): Promise<Team>
    {
        const team: Team = await this.teamRepository.firstWhere('id', 1);

        return this.teamRepository.save(team);
    }
}
```

**team.module.ts**

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {TeamService} from '@Domain/Team/Services/team.service';
import {TypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {Team} from '@Domain/Team/Models/team.entity';
import {TeamRepository} from '@Domain/Team/Repositories/team.repository';

@Module({
            imports:   [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Team])],
            exports:   [TeamService],
            providers: [TeamService, TeamRepository],
        })
export class TeamModule
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this is what I was looking for! It works on MongoDB too.

Comment: Thank you @Nick This was so helpful! It does work with mongo too, obviously just swapping out the extension in the repository to extend from MongoRepository instead of a regular one.  I was struggling with this for like a week thank you for posting!

Comment: Thank you Nick, got this working. Seems much simpler than an alternative approach outlined here - https://gist.github.com/anchan828/9e569f076e7bc18daf21c652f7c3d012

Comment: Great job on figuring this out. Really appreciate it :).

Comment: How can we write unit test for the repository with this? I need to provide dependency for data source

Comment: @IshikaJain did you managed to find a proper solution? I saw this solution for unit tests (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing), but I'm struggling with e2e tests.

Comment: I 'm also really struggling to find a way to test team.repository.ts with jest as others have.  I keep getting error like: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the XYZRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.  If anyone has managed to do it, please share.

Comment: I meant, I'm trying to test a service that uses the team.repository.ts

Comment: Inside tests using jest, dataSource will be undefined

Answer (score 11):

The way you can create a custom repository for mongo in `TypeORM` it with the following way:

**users.repository.ts**

Here instead of using `@EntityRepository` you will use the `@Injectable` decorator, and for inject, the `schema` will use MongoRepository

```
// users.repository.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MongoRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: MongoRepository<User>,
  ) {}

  async createUser(firstName: string, lastName: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = new User({
      firstName,
      lastName,
    });

    await this.usersRepository.save(user);

    return user;
  }
  

   //write other helpful methods here(find, delete, etc...)


}
```

**users.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository) {}

  async createUser(firstName: string, lastName: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.createUser(firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```

**users.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersRepository } from './database/repository/UsersRepository';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersRepository, UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I think it's almost there to what I was looking for! But there's one issue with this, it seems like it will only expose one function from `UsersRepository` which is the `createUser()` I created. But I can't use common functions of a repository like `.find()`, `.updateOne()`, etc with the custom `UsersRepository` in the `UsersService`, how to make it such that it would be an extension of a repository?

Comment: @unspeakable29 the best way to do that it creating an abstract class base repository, in this base repository implement all that you need(find(), findById(), findOne(), etc..), and in UsersRepository just extend the BaseRepository.

Comment: I see. I guess that's the best way huh. It used to be easier with `EntityRepository` but oh well. Thanks for the help! 

Answer (score 4):

```
// task.entity.ts
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;
}
```

```
// tasks.repository.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './tast.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {
  constructor(dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(Task, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
}
```

```
//tasks.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { Task } from './tast.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task])], // NOTICE: HERE
  controllers: [TasksController], // NOTICE: HERE
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Task) // NOTICE: here
    private readonly tasksRepository: TasksRepository,
  ) {}

  async getTaskById(id: string): Promise<Task> {
    const task = this.tasksRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    });

    if (!task) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Task with id ${id} not found`);
    }

    return task;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just developed a package that solves this problem, you can check it out.

[nestjs-typeorm-custom-repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typeorm-custom-repository)

```
// users.repository.ts
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { EntityRepository } from 'nestjs-typeorm-custom-repository';

import { User } from './user.entity';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UsersRepository extends Repository<User> {}
```

```
// users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
  ) {}
  ...
  }
}
```

```
// users.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CustomRepositoryModule } from 'nestjs-typeorm-custom-repository';

import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [CustomRepositoryModule.forFeature([UsersRepository])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@deprecated — use Repository.extend function to create a custom repository

please write like that

```
export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
    findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        return this.createQueryBuilder("user")
            .where("user.firstName = :firstName", { firstName })
            .andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName", { lastName })
            .getMany()
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this approach. Works fine.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { PlaygroundEntity } from 'src/entities/playground.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class PlaygroundRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(PlaygroundEntity)
    private readonly _repository: Repository<PlaygroundEntity>,
  ) {}

  public get _() {
    return this._repository;
  }

  async findWithCriteria() {
    return this._.find({ where: { datecolumn: new Date() } });
  }
}
```

Inject it like a normal provider.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PlaygroundRepository } from './repositories/pg.repository';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(PlaygroundRepository)
    private pgRepository: PlaygroundRepository,
  ) {}

  async start() {
    const customMethod = await this.pgRepository.findWithCriteria();

    const defaultMethod = await this.pgRepository._.find();
  }
}
```

Seems clean and intuitive enough.