# How to extend TypeORM repository in NestJS 9 (TypeORM 3.+)

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, orm, nestjs, typeorm

Previously, TypeORM repository could be extended and injected directly into services, e.g.:

```js
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UsersRepo extends Repository<User> {
  // my custom repo methods
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { UsersRepo } from './users.repo';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private readonly usersRepo: UsersRepo) {}
}
```

But since version 3.0.0 TypeORM [does not support repository extending via inheritance](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1).

How to achieve such behavior in NestJS 9 (which depends on TypeORM 3.+)? The only solution I came up with is to add custom methods to the service layer. But I would like to keep all ORM-related methods (query, aggregations, etc.) in the repository layer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let me tell you straight away: I have no idea whether this is a recommended solution, I don't know if the authors of TypeORM actually considered such approach at all. But what I just did a minute ago is this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {


  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
      repository: Repository<UserEntity>
  ) {
    super(repository.target, repository.manager, repository.queryRunner);
  }
}
```

And the best part: it worked :D

I use:
`"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.0"` just so you know.

I will keep checking if it doesn't break anything, but for now, seems like a good workaround.

Answer (score 8):

Hope helpful for you:

---

```
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { EntityTarget } from 'typeorm/common/EntityTarget';

export class GenericRepository<T> extends Repository<T> {
  constructor(target: EntityTarget<T>, dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(target, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

  async someCommonMethod() {
    return {};
  }
}
```

---

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../../entities/User';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GenericRepository } from '../common/generic.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends GenericRepository<User> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(User, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
}
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from '../../entities/User';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solved here (similar to the other answers here, but more complete):
[How to do custom repository using TypeORM (MongoDB) in NestJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549668/how-to-do-custom-repository-using-typeorm-mongodb-in-nestjs)

Not sure why they deprecated @EntityRepository because this is more complicated, but it works

Answer (score 0):

hope helpful for you.
In my **UserServices**

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private readonly repository: BaseRepository<UserEntity>,
) {}
```

**UserModule**

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  exports: [UserService],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

*note: **BaseRepository** from [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)