# NestJS Repository gives error 'No metadata for "TaskRepository" was found.'

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, repository-pattern, nestjs-typeorm

GitHub link to project:
[nestjs-task-management](https://github.com/saif-ali-xint/nestjs-task-management.git)

Error Log:

```
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +115ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +182ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [InstanceLoader] TasksModule dependencies initialized +2ms  
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [RoutesResolver] TasksController {/tasks}: +28ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/tasks/:id, GET} route +5ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 11:22:29     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +4ms
[Nest] 15824  - 23/08/2023, 12:03:53   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "TaskRepository" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "TaskRepository" was found.
    at DataSource.getMetadata (D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:444:30)
    at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\src\repository\Repository.ts:53:40)
    at Repository.findOne (D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\src\repository\Repository.ts:577:42)
    at TasksService.getTaskById (D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\src\tasks\tasks.service.ts:37:50)
    at TasksController.getTaskById (D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\src\tasks\tasks.controller.ts:24:30)
    at D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at D:\SaifAli\NestJS Demo Projects\nestjs-task-management\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Modules:

```
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
```

typeorm.config.ts:

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'taskmanagement',
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
    synchronize: true,
};
```

tasks.module.ts:

```
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { TaskRepository } from './task.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TaskRepository])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

task.entity.ts:

```
import { TaskStatus } from "./task-status.enum";
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Task {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @Column()
    status: TaskStatus;
}
```

task.repository.ts:

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

export class TaskRepository extends Repository<Task> {
  // Your custom repository methods can go here
}
```

tasks.service.ts:

```
import { TaskRepository } from './task.repository';
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TaskRepository)
        private taskRepository: TaskRepository,
    ) {};
    async getTaskById(id: number): Promise<Task> {
        const record = await this.taskRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
        if (!record) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return record;
    }
}
```

I tried using an older version of TypeORM but that was introducing new errors and I want to learn doing this using the up-to-date methods.

I only get this error when I hit the endpoint using Postman and I have been trying to fix this since yesterday and was unable to find any similar issues. One was to use `entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],` in the typeorm config file where I was using `autoLoadEntities: true` instead so I tried that too but didn't change anything.

I don't understand where and how I have to provide metadata to the repository.

I thank you guys in advance for any help here.

Comment: Found solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549668/how-to-do-custom-repository-using-typeorm-mongodb-in-nestjs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957962/how-to-extend-typeorm-repository-in-nestjs-9-typeorm-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code is incorrect. Instead of `TaskRepository`, it needs to be
`Task` (from `task.entity.ts`)

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TaskRepository])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

So to fix this, you need to change this to:

```
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task])],
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

---

Your second issue is how you instantiated the repository with `TaskService`.

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TaskRepository)
        private taskRepository: TaskRepository,
    ) {};
}
```

You need to use `Task` here as well, instead of `TaskRepository`.

```
import { MongoRepository } from 'typeorm'

import { Task } from './task.entity'

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Task)
        private taskRepository: MongoRepository<Task>,
    ) {};
}
```

Now, you don't even need a class called `TaskRepository`.

Comment: I tried that but it gives this error:
`ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TasksService (?). Please make sure that the argument TaskRepository at index [0] is available in the TasksModule context.` and if I use `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task]), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TaskRepository])],` instead, I get the same error as before.

Comment: @SAIFALI Updated my answer. Can you check?

Comment: thanks for the update, it works fine now but now I'm using MongoRepository instead of a custom built repository, I'll try using my custom repository later though and check how I can get it to work, thanks.

Comment: I actually got my custom repository working too, I just replaced:
`private taskRepository: MongoRepository<Task>,`
with:
`private taskRepository: TaskRepository<Task>,`
And in my repository file I replaced:
`export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {}`
with:
`export class TasksRepository<Task> extends Repository<Task> {}`
Not sure if it's the right way but I got it working with my custom repository.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by reverting @nestjs/typeorm to version 8.0.0 (`yarn upgrade @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.0`) and downgrading typeorm to version 0.2.32 (`yarn upgrade typeorm@0.2.32`).