# Trying to use in Nestjs Custom Repository typeorm

Tags: nestjs, repository, typeorm

by example:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549668/how-to-do-custom-repository-using-typeorm-mongodb-in-nestjs][1]

Created custom repository в yandex-ndd-api-client.module:

```
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
// import {Team} from '@Domain/Team/Models/team.entity';
import { TestRepositoryTypeorm } from '../entity/testRepositoryTypeorm.entity';
 
@Injectable()
export class TestRepository extends Repository<TestRepositoryTypeorm> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(TestRepositoryTypeorm, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
  async findTest(): Promise<any> { //TestRepositoryTypeorm | undefined
    const findTests = await this.dataSource
      .getRepository(TestRepositoryTypeorm)
      .createQueryBuilder('test')
      .getMany();
    return await findTests;
  }
}
```

Connected in the module::

```
 providers: [YandexDeliveryService, YandexNddApiClientService, ConfigService, SyncService, TestRepository],
```

Connected it to the service yandex-ndd-api-client.service:

```
import { TestRepository } from './repository/testRepositoryTypeorm.retository';
 
@Injectable()
export class YandexNddApiClientService {
  constructor(
    // private yandexDeliveryApiService: YandexDeliveryApiService,
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private dataSource: DataSource,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
    // @InjectRepository(TestRepository)
    private testRepository: TestRepository,
  ) {}
```

Called in service:

```
//testRepositoryTypeorm
  async testRepositoryTypeorm(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      console.log('testRepositoryTypeorm');
      // return 'testRepositoryTypeorm';
      return await this.testRepository.findTest();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR testRepositoryTypeorm:', e);
    }
 
  }
```

As a result:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the YandexNddApiClientService (HttpService, DataSource, ConfigService, winston, ?, SchedulerRegistry). Please make sure that the argument TestRepository at index [4] is available in the DetmirApiClientModule context.
 
Potential solutions:
- If TestRepository is a provider, is it part of the current DetmirApiClientModule?
- If TestRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within DetmirApiClientModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing TestRepository */ ]
  })


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549668/how-to-do-custom-repository-using-typeorm-mongodb-in-nestjs
```

DetmirApiClientModule.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DetmirApiClientService } from './detmir-api-client.service';
import { DetmirApiClientController } from './detmir-api-client.controller';
import { SyncService } from 'src/sync.service';
import { YandexNddApiClientService } from 'src/yandex-ndd-api-client/yandex-ndd-api-client.service';
import { HttpModule, HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { YandexNddApiClientModule } from 'src/yandex-ndd-api-client/yandex-ndd-api-client.module';

@Module({
  providers: [DetmirApiClientService, SyncService, YandexNddApiClientService],
  controllers: [DetmirApiClientController],
  imports: [HttpModule, YandexNddApiClientModule], //TestRepository
})
export class DetmirApiClientModule {}
```

Comment: Show your `DetmirApiClientModule` class

Comment: @JayMcDoniel
I do not understand, where does the other module? (DetmirApiClientModule) If I don't need it now.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `YandexNddApiClientModule` does not add the `YandexNddApiClientService` to the `exports` array. Add `YandexNddApiClientService` to the exports if it is not already there and remove `YandexNddApiClientService` from the `providers` array of `DetmirApiClientModule`. The error is being raised because you have `YandexNddApiClientService` declared in the `providers` of `DetmirApiClientModule` so Nest is trying to create the provider in the new module rather than re-use the module from its original context